# Show modal on url change in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show a user registration modal on url change in AngularJS. I'm using Angular routing and my route configs is as follows:

```
var sgApp = angular.module('sgApp', [
        'ngRoute',
    ]);

sgApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/',{
            templateUrl: '/static/partials/index.html',
            controller: 'indexCtrl'
        }).when('/user-signup',{
            controller: 'userSignUpCtrl'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

In controllers:

```
sgApp.controller('userSignUpCtrl',['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http){
        $('#modal-target').modal('show');
    }
]);
```

However, this isn't working as on changing url to `/user-signup`, the modal doesn't show up. What am I missing?

Comment: Bootstrap's modal? Do you have Bootstrap's JS code and jQuery included? I'd also recommend using the ui-bootstrap library in an Angular app rather than the Bootstrap JS.

Comment: @Phil I do have those files included. I'll also check ui bootstrap library

Comment: Before you go too far down the jQuery bootstrap path, know that (1) there are angular directives for this stuff here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ , and (2) If you're trying to do something using jQuery, you're probably taking the wrong approach, especially if you're trying to do it in a controller. It _can_ work, but really almost any code that might need jQuery functionality should be done in a directive (but you don't even need that in this case anyway).

Comment: If you pop an alert into that controller, does it run?
alert('foo');

Comment: @Hank, Popping an alert doesn't work either. I've just started using `ui-bootstrap`. So I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no element with **#modal-target** as id yet so the view was not rendered.

You can put in a timeout and give some delay for showing the modal or can use the angularui modal approach with a template.